# Why can't I see questions' views while on my Windows phone?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I am logged in from my Windows phone, but I cannot see the views that a question has.

Is there any way to see them?

Comment: Also, how can I upload a photo from my Windows phone here? I have a screenshot from a question

Comment: @Shev Upload the picture somewhere and use the image syntax: ![alt text](utl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to see the views a question has from the mobile site. If you want to see the views you will need to click "full site" at the bottom of the page to get the main (not mobile) site.

Answer (score 1):

For the apps and mobile sites the functionality is limited a bit and views are considered to be excess. You can, however, click "full site" link in the footer, the full sites have the views shown.